# How many SQS Queues and Lambdas to use to retry failed messages in an async system

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-sqs, retry-logic

I am trying to design a basic asynchronous log streaming system using common AWS technologies and wanted some pointers.

The use case is simply streaming cloudwatch log events through kinesis data stream and then into a lambda which performs some transformations on the logs and then sends them to another service. I think since I am using AWS services with good retry mechanisms and fault tolerance it is at the tail of my system I need to focus on making resilient and fault tolerant.  We can't afford to drop log events in this system.

It seems to me that we can probably use a SQS queue where we can place failed messages to be retried.

I feel at minimum we would need another lambda that picks up messages from this queue to be retried. If the lambda fails again it can send the messages to a DLQ where we can go and inspect and manually re-drive.

In the retry lambda the code will probably be very similar to the original lambda function that processes the log events, it will make the same call again for the failed messages.

The service we call throws various different exceptions, some of them such as throttling exceptions we can retry based on.

Does this sound right? Is there a more common pattern used for these sorts of cases? It would be good to read some good articles on this if anyone has links.

Thanks

Comment: Are those transformations complex? Unless they are very complex (and you don't rely on Unit Tests) or dependent on an external service, I don't see the point to retry them. Just log the failure so that you can analyze it later.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Data Transformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) as the consumer of your Kinesis Firehose. This lets you setup the Lambda logic like you want to, with AWS-managed buffering and asynchronous invocation. You can then use [Failure-Handling Features for Kinesis and DynamoDB Event Sources](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-failure-handling-features-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/)